# UINavigation bar showing a weird white space in place of text label when UIImagePickerController presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a view from which I want to present a UIImagePicker Camera or Photos according to what user chooses. But when I present my picker controller, my navigation bar is black and a weird white background appears instead of the label.

For camera

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            [[picker navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


            picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
            picker.delegate = self;
            //[picker setAllowsEditing:YES];
            [self.delegate presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For Photo picker from Album

```
 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            [[picker navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


//            picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            //picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
            picker.delegate = self;
            //[picker setAllowsEditing:YES];
            [self.delegate presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This is the image when I try to pick up from Photos (Gallery)

[image]

and this image is when I try to open camera.
[image]

They have this weird navigation bar which I guess is generally replaced by ImagePicker's when we present a pickerViewController.

Comment: Have you tried present UIImagePickerController with [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil]. Please remove self.delegate and check.

Comment: Nope it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen because UIImagePickerController is subclass of UINavigationController with its own stack of controllers (and its own navbar).

One tricky solution is use container controller:
Create picker in container controller init method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        _picker =  [UIImagePickerController new];
        _picker.delegate = self;
        _picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear]) {
            _picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
        }
        _picker.mediaTypes = @[(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
        _picker.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Add picker as child vc and hide it's navbar:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor;
    [self.picker setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    [self addChildViewController:self.picker];
    [self.picker didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.picker.view];
}
```

Layout it's frame:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGFloat kNavbarHeight = 64;
    self.picker.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, kNavbarHeight, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) - kNavbarHeight);
}
```

Now you can push or modally present container:

```
UIViewController *vc = [EHPickerContainerController new];
vc.title = @"Test";

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

[image]

It's cool that you can include a picker into the storyboard flow via this container controller.